# Typedef structure's member being static or not in c

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef, storage-class-specifier

I think this none sense doesnt that? because after creating instance from that variable. It will initialize that variable whole, will not behave differently to members an will initialize all of them, doesn't that? As I know static variables are global variable but their usage are restricted to specified function or source file.

```
typedef struct
{
    const uint32_t mainpointer;
    static uint32_t currentpointer;    
    uint16_t num_el;    
    uint8_t num_byte;    
}arrayPushCirc_doublebuffer_instance;

void main(void)
{
arrayPushCirc_doublebuffer_instance struction;
function1(struction);
}
```

Comment: The code isn't valid C code. Where did you get it from? Who gave it to you?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is part of my own code, ported here to asking my rized question, answered by "Vlad from Moscow". I'm a begginer programmer if you could please tell briefly why this is  not valid. Or if you could suggesting me a material to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C data members of a structure may not have storage class specifiers.

So this declaration of a data member

```
static uint32_t currentpointer;
```

is invalid in C.

According to the C Grammar data member declarations may have only the following specifiers

```
specifier-qualifier-list:
    type-specifier specifier-qualifier-listopt
    type-qualifier specifier-qualifier-listopt
```

On the other hand, you may use the storage class specifier static for declarations of objects in the file scope or a function scope.

For example

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    const uint32_t mainpointer;
    uint32_t currentpointer;    
    uint16_t num_el;    
    uint8_t num_byte;    
}arrayPushCirc_doublebuffer_instance;

static arrayPushCirc_doublebuffer_instance struction; 

int main( void )
{
    //...
}
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: But the whole struct have? because storage allocated by whole struction initialization?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd A typedef declaration also may not have the storage specifier static or extern.

Comment: You mean `static arrayPushCirc_doublebuffer_instance struction;` is also wrong?!

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd The structure declaration in this typedef is wrong because its data member has a storage class specifier. And if you will use a storage class specifier in the typedef declaration for the whole structure then it also will be incorrect.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd As for this declaration of an object arrayPushCirc_doublebuffer_instance struction; then it may have a storage class specifier in its declaration.

Comment: If it's possible to make a `arrayPushCirc_doublebuffer_instance` variable static, could you provide a correct example in your answer?

Comment: That will be insightfull.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd See my appended post.

Comment: Assume I've declared `arrayPushCirc_doublebuffer_instance` in a specific function after each time calling that function the variable will be resetting unless I've declare globally or statically as you've told.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd If you will declare it within a function with the storage class static then it will be initialized only once independent on haw many times the function is called.

Comment: Then you must change "in the file scope" to "in the file or function scope." thanks.